# AudioQueue not playing the PCM I provide

Tags: swift, audioqueueservices

I am trying to play pcm data in an iOS app using AudioQueues. I provide the pcm data in a `buffer` like so:

`status = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(audioQueue!, buffer!, 0, nil)`

where the buffer has been filled with:

`memcpy(buffer!.pointee.mAudioData, outPCMData, outPCMData.count)`
`buffer!.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize = UInt32(outPCMData.count)`

and I can see that the buffer contains the correct data since if I output the bytes to a file, I can play it with `ffplay` and it sounds as expected.

The ASBD is configured as:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription(mSampleRate: 44100,
                                        mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
                                        mFormatFlags: kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked,
                                        mBytesPerPacket: 2,
                                        mFramesPerPacket: 1,
                                        mBytesPerFrame: 2 ,
                                        mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
                                        mBitsPerChannel: 16,
                                        mReserved: 0)
```

Any ideas as to where could I look to know how to fix it?

Cheers

Comment: Anybody? //////

Comment: I notice that if I set the mAudioDataByteSize to the double of the value I am using, then I get sound, but it does not sound good because the mAudioDataByteSize is incorrect I guess

Comment: How do you know the ASBD config matches the actual config of the PCM you are trying to play? Since you mention `ffplay` with `--verbose` or `ffprobe` you should get more data what it detects.